# Angular 2 - ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, typescript, draggable, dragula, ng2-dragula

```
<column *ngFor="let col of columns">
  ...
  <div [dragula]="'tickets-list'" [dragulaModel]="col.tickets">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let ticket of col.tickets">
        {{ ticket }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</column>
```

I have few columns. Every column contain array with tickets. How can I detect which ticket moved and where?

Answer (score 1):

Add id to your dragula Div. In your case use col.id

**step -1**

```
  <div  id={{col.id}}  [dragula]="'tickets-list'" [dragulaModel]="col.tickets">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let ticket of col.tickets">
            {{ ticket }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**step 2**  subscribe drop event.

```
 dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value) => {
                this.onDropModel(value.slice(1));
            });
```

**step 3**
on the on the onDrag(value) function  args are ***el, target, source, sibling***

value[1] ==> target.id
value[2] ==> source.id
based on the id you can detect ticket moved between columns